# Series of Functions - Investigate Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm asked to investigate the uniform convergence of the following series of function : $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log{(1 + nx)}}{nx^n}, \;\; x \in [2, \infty).$$

**My work so far:**

Using the inequality: $\forall{x} \in \mathbb{R}: \log{x} \leq x - 1$ we have

$$\left| f_n(x) \right| = \left| \frac{\log{(1 + nx)}}{nx^n} \right| \leq \frac{(1 + nx) - 1}{nx^n} = \frac{1}{x^{n-1}} \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.$$

I know I have to use the *Weierstrass M-test* but I'm note sure if I need to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{n-1}} < \infty$ or if I need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} < \infty$. Which one do I need to show and how?

Comment: In the Weierstraß $M$-test, the bounds on $f_n$ don't depend on the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already bounded the absolute value of the general term of the series with a geometric series of constants, the sum of which converges independently of $x.$ No more sophistication needed, then: the epsilon-delta definition of uniform convergence is there.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. Just to clarify: since the geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}}$ converges independently of x it follows that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[2,\infty)$. Is that correct?

Comment: It is, as can be verified explicitly using the definition of uniform convergence (the exact position of the quantorial 'for all $x$' does not bother us when $x$ is not even part of our upper bound anymore)